# Sort data based on my location and predefine city name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

I am Using AngularJs and Ionic for Hybrid Mobile App development.
I am getting this data from API

```
[{"Location":"Brierfield"},
 {"Location":"Centreville"},
 {"Location":"Chelsea"},
 {"Location":"Coosa Pines"},
 {"Location":"Clanton"}]
```

With the help of below code I am getting my current location

```
var position = {}; 
         var onSuccess = function(position2) { 
              console.log(position2.coords.latitude )
              console.log(position2.coords.longitude) 
              position.latitude = position2.coords.latitude;
              position.longitude = position2.coords.longitude; 
              $rootScope.$digest()
          }; 
        function onError(error) {  
            alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                  'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        } 
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError); 
        return position;
```

I have to check based on my current location and above data(Location) which city is near by me and based on that I need to sort my data in View.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with either angularjs or ionic. I think you would have more success if you phrased your question as a pure javascript/google-maps question...

Answer (score 0):

It will be great if you can get lat & long data of the locations from the api. Getting your current position and location data you can use [Haversine Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)  to calculate the distance between two points.

In case you are not able to get position details from API then you have to get the coordinates of the location and use the [Haversine Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: You can also see this link to calculate distance using javascript - http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html